Server threads vs JVM threads
Let's take a java web service. Now, we hit an endpoint from a client and the request is received by a server (Apache Tomcat) thread. And then this server thread handovers the request execution part to the JVM thread?
I am a bit confused about what happens during this interaction. How the server & JVM and their threads interactions work?
This is mostly a knowledge question. I tried to read many articles. I understood the Threads from both are independent to each other. But there is still confusion as to how the interaction happens between these two.

"take a web service" ok, "request is received" with you so far, "server thread handovers the request execution part to JVM thread" ??? now you lost me, what does that mean? "Threads from both are independent to each other" may be the source of your confusion, where did you get that? Anyway, this kinda fails the 'practical problem' part of on-topic, even if you had a perfect answer to this, would it enable you to do something useful?

Let's ignore the optional native bits of tomcat. So the server is running in a JVM, it is a bunch of threads sleeping and waiting for requests. When a request comes one of those is woken up and handles the request. Does this view meet with your question? I can't really tell.

@teapot418 Imagine a small java program being run, we don't need Tomcat in this case right but there are threads(A) that is executing this program. But when we are building a web service, we use a server like tomcat server where threads(B) accept request from client, correct? Now threads A & threads B. What are they? Are they same? How do they differentiate?

Java doesn't have "server threads" and "jvm threads". Java has threads. Tomcat is running within the JVM and uses threads - the same kind of threads that a command line application uses, the same kind of threads that a GUI application uses.

What Kläger said plus… You don’t really care as the author of a web app. All you care about is what the Servlet spec promises: Each request delivered to your web app (your “context”) results in a Servlet method invoked on your HttpServlet implementation class while running in its own thread. (The SingleThreadModel having been removed.)

If you aren't talking about virtual thread or green thread, then there are no separation between server thread and JVM thread. JVM thread is an OS (server) thread.
When you run Java web server, it creates a bunch of threads (thread pool). No matter what the implementation of thread pool, eventually the Thread class is used. However, the implementation of Thread makes a bunch of syscalls to OS in order for OS to create a thread on its level. E.g. new Thread translates to pthread_create:
class Thread {

    public Thread(Runnable r) {
         this.runnable = r;
         _createThread();
    }

    private native void _createThread(); // implemented in C++ as part of JVM
}

The implementation of a server thread on OS level then executes a C++ "adapter" function which is part of the Java Runtime. The task of this "adapter" function is to delegate execution to the Java code.
void * adapter_function(void *params) {
    JVM_Object obj = JVM_GetObject(params);
    JVM_String methodName = JVM_NewString("run");
    JVM_ExecuteJavaMethod(obj, methodName);
}

For the web server, the method (implemented in Java) is provided by the web server itself (e.g. Tomcat) and just waits for a new task in a blocking queue.
The you hit the endpoint, there's another Thread which just waits on the socket and upon receiving a new request puts request into the queue.
Definitely it's only a one way to implement the server, yet I hope it helps clarifying how threads work
